# JavaFX - Dealing with duplicate children error - RadioButtons

Tags: java, javafx

I have three radio buttons, I want my GUI to be uploaded depend on the checkbox I click.

I had referred to this guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/radio-button.htm
which seems ideal for my needs. However, it cannot recognize the type despite importing the correct libraries. I decided to write my own little code.

We have horizontal boxes and vertical boxes. I have added the labels and text elements into one horizontal box (indicated by hb, hb1, hb2..) and clubs them all together in one vertical box.

Here is my code for event listener for my radio button:

```
test1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        try{
            //Remove all existing children
            vb.getChildren().removeAll(hb,hb2,hb3,hb4,hb5);
            log("Cleared");
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            log(e.getMessage());
        }
        try{
            //Add email and email text into a horizontal box
            hb.getChildren().addAll(email, email_text);
            hb.setSpacing(10);
            //Added the box to the vertical box
            vb.getChildren().add(hb);

            log("Added the email input box");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Declarations:

```
final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

final RadioButton test1 = new RadioButton("Test 1");
test1.setToggleGroup(group);
grid.add(test1, 0, 1);

final RadioButton test2 = new RadioButton("Test 2");
test2.setToggleGroup(group);
grid.add(test2, 0, 2);

final  VBox vb = new VBox(10); // main container
final HBox hb = new HBox(); // Email , Email Text
final HBox hb2 = new HBox(); // Corporate , Corporate Name
```

I am getting an error : `Children: duplicate children added: parent = HBox@359889fd`.  I did a little research on this : [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = VBox@872be7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044935/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-children-duplicate-children-added-parent) . Honestly, even if we both are working on the same issue, I am having a real hard time getting his code.

My main issue: If I am removing ALL the element in the beginning, why is there a duplicate error?

Perhaps, my code may be completely wrong and made no sense. Do you recommend any other approach?

Comment: Possibly you get error when adding to `hb`. When removing from `vb` also remove from `hb`

Comment: Hey! Vb contains ALL the hb elements. If I remove Vb's children...shouldn't the hb be removed?

Comment: Do you have error when adding to `hb`? (second try-catch). If yes, it means you already have some elements there, try to remove them (duplicates) before you add (email, email_text). Right now you are removing only from `vb`. You have to be specific where exactly you get this error.

Comment: The first time I click on any checkbox , I get "Cleared
Added the email input box"  Second time I click on any checkbox i get "Cleared" and then "Children: duplicate children added: parent = HBox@359889fd"

Comment: The thing is, I AM removing them as soon as I click ANY checkbox (first checkbox) but it says its a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was I was removing the vb box but I was not removing the contents of hb. Whereas, I am adding hb. I should have also removed from hb.

Comment: Yes it did! I wish you posted it as an answer!